# I want to disconnect firestore updates for a user who has entered the background

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

After a few minutes in the `background`, I want to disconnect from the `firestore` after determining that the user has already finished using the app.

However, in the code below, `eventWhenBackground` is activated as soon as it is in the `foreground`.

How do I get my app to go into the `background` and run a few minutes later?

thank you.

(Please point out if my native language is not English and my grammar is incorrect.)

#### Code

---

```swift
// SceneDelegate
    //The code is simplified here
    let eventWhenBackground = DispatchWorkItem() {
        //firestoreObserver.remove()
        print("Successfully deleted firestoreObserver!!")
    }
    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        print("Foreground!")
    }
    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        print("Background!")
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 180, execute: eventWhenBackground)
    }

//output
=> Background!
=> //Nothing happens after 180 seconds.

=> //When I got back to foreground.
=> Successfully deleted firestoreObserver!!
=> Foreground!
```

Comment: The behavior you have tested and described (quite beautifully) in your simplified code is exactly what is expected, given how iOS apps work. We go into the background; your app is suspended (frozen); and whatever it was in the middle of doing when it was suspended, is done when / if we come back to the foreground and the app is unfrozen. You've demonstrated that very nicely. It is unclear, however, what the question is. If you don't want something to happen because the app went into the background, then run _away_ from that thing, not _towards_ it as your code is doing.

Comment: I understand that it is not possible to run the app in the background.
Thank you very much.

Comment: It is possible. But that isn't what you asked.